# "Value cannot be null" exception while loading WorkflowServicesManager

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, csom

I am trying to start a list workflow in SharePoint 2013 using client object model. But while loading WorkflowServicesManager, it throws the error below -

> Value cannot be null 
> Parameter name: uriString

The code I am using is like below :

```
    public void StartWorkflow() 
    {
        ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("<site url>");
        ctx.Load( ctx.Web );
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        WorkflowServicesManager wfSvcMan = new WorkflowServicesManager( ctx, ctx.Web );
        ctx.Load( wfSvcMan );

        //executing this throws error "Value cannot be null"
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: is it a console app?

Comment: Yes, a console app

Comment: Check whether the person whose account u r running have adequate permissions on site.

Comment: Check whether the person whose account u are running have right on site.Check ctx.web is not null

Comment: The user is the Administrator. And have all access to the Site. Also the ctx.Web is not null